# Filter Multi-Dimension Array Using Binary Map (Logical Indexing Inefficient)

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, filter

I am new to matlab so I am having some trouble finding the most efficient way to execute this task.

I am trying to filter out one matrix M using a second matrix N.

M = AxBxCxD where A,B,C,D are on the order of ~150 each
N = AxBxC. Same A,B,C above. Its entries are binary.

I wish to filter matrix M so it only contains data where entries in the N matrix are 1. Additionally, I want it to be a two dimensional array SxD where S is the number of elements that are 1 in N

I have tried two methods so far, both which are either too memory intensive or slow:

1)

```
indx = find(N(:));
[X,Y,Z] = ind2sub(size(M),indx);
result = squeeze(M(X,Y,Z,:));
```

In the third time, the result of M(X,Y,Z,:) is way to big to hold in memory.

2)

```
l = logical(N) ;
map = repmat(l,'length of D dimension');
M(map);
%Reduce dimension next
```

But the computation time to build repmat(l,280) is considerable.

Are there any more efficient ways to computer this result. Perhaps apply the mask to each row along the D dimension in M  (I looked into this but wasn't able to figure anything out).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with logical indexing. I think this is the right dimensions, but I always have trouble thinking about 4D.

```
N = (rand(5, 7, 10) < 0.5);
M = rand(size(N,1), size(N,2), size(N,3), 3);

%Use reshape to go from a AxBxCxD array to an A*B*C x D matrix
m = reshape(M, numel(N), []);
M2 = m(N(:), :);
```